# Triangular numbers

Tags: c, numbers, geometry

Hello I am trying to write a program that gives me the triangular numbers of every 5th number 5 through 50. It has to be set up in a table.  I got the table to work, with every 5th number 5 through 50. However, the triangular numbers are coming up as that too! I do not think my program is looping.

Also, my book says I have to use the formula triangularNumber = n(n+1)/2 but I keep getting an error.

Here is the bottom half of my program ( the stars are a banner needed for my class but I assure you everything is correct in the top half)

```
int main() {

    // [... snipped ... ]

    printf("***********************************************************\n\n\n\n\n");

    int n, triangularNumber;

    triangularNumber = n (n + 1) / 2;

    printf ("TABLE OF EVERY 5TH TRIANGULAR NUMBER\n\n");
    printf (" n    Sum from 1 to n\n");
    printf ("--- ------------------\n");

    for ( n = 5; n <= 50; n +=5 )  {
        triangularNumber = n;

        printf ("  %i         %i\n", n, triangularNumber );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `triangularNumber = n;` in the loop?

Comment: `triangularNumber = n * (n + 1) / 2;` You are missing the `*`. Also, you need to move that line within the loop ...

Answer (score 1):

The line `triangularNumber = n (n + 1) / 2` is in the wrong place; the calculation only occurs on that line, at which point `n` is uninitialised.

You need to move the calculation inside the loop so that it happens for every `n`:

```
for ( n = 5; n <= 50; n +=5 )  {
    triangularNumber = n * (n + 1) / 2;
    printf ("  %i         %i\n", n, triangularNumber );
}
```

If your intent was to give the definition of how `triangularNumber` should be calculated, the way to do it in C is to write a function, e.g.:

```
int triangularNumber (int n) {
    return n * (n + 1) / 2;
}
```

And then call `triangularNumber(n)` to obtain the value. (In this case the formula is short and only used in one place, so there little need to write the function.)

Also note that in C you can't write `n(n + 1)` for multiplication, you need to use the `*` operator as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually compute the value. Change this line `printf ("  %i         %i\n", n, triangularNumber );` to `printf ("  %i         %i\n", n, n * (n+1) / 2 );`

Comment: @dvnrrs yup, I did forget. Updated it now, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

triangularNumber should be a function, not a variable. Try this.

```
int triangularNumber (int n)
{
    return n * (n + 1) / 2;
}
```